# Creating a Smooth line on Picture Box(winforms,c#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

First the code

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

            System.Drawing.Graphics g;
            System.Drawing.SolidBrush brush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            g.FillRectangle(brush, e.X, e.Y, 5, 5);

    }
```

This event handler would fire up whenever the mouse moves over a picture box and create a pixel. Now the problem is that as long as i move the mouse slowly all those pixels form a line. However whenever i move the mouse a bit fast the line breaks and all i see are dots with wide spaces in between them.

Need help in this matter.

Comment: How come you're not [drawing an actual line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawline.aspx)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is sort of a free form line with no actual point. Wherever the user moves the mouse the line extends.

Comment: It sounds like your getting the break because of the processing speed of your application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the mouse is moved, you won't get a `MouseMove` event for every single pixel traveled by the mouse pointer. You'll get them at a fairly consistent time interval, so the faster the mouse moves, the further apart the points you'll get.

What you need to do is store the position of the last point received, and draw an actual line using `DrawLine` between the old position and the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the comments that have been made, what you will have to do is interpolate a line between the last point your mouse was calculated at and the point where your mouse is now. This will create a free flowing line as your comment suggests you want.

If you interpolate instead of `draw line` then it would be possible to make your lines curved.. obviously drawing a line between these points requires less processing time and may suffice

Answer (score 1):

I would never suggest to perform actual drawing outside of the overridden Paint method. Rather, call `Invalidate()`.

I would edit your code in this way:

```
void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Store necessary painting data from e
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    //Handle painting logic
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are effectively drawing points alone a line, and the application can't keep up with the input (you don't get a MouseEvent invoke for every pixel the mouse passes over/through).

You'll need to keep track of the mouse position for the previous frame, then you can draw a smooth **line** between that point and the current. You could set the 'old' position on the mouseEnter/mouseDown (whatever you want) and do the drawing on mouse move thus. It's important that you make sure you set the `oldMousePos` variable before doing any drawing, else you will have lines all over the place (might even be worth having a check variable to make sure it is up-do-date).

Drawing code:

```
private System.Drawing.Point oldMousePos; // old mouse position

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        System.Drawing.Point curMousePos = e.Location;
        System.Drawing.Graphics g;
        System.Drawing.Pen brush = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Blue, 5); // width of 5
        g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawLine(brush, oldMousePos.X, oldMousePos.Y, curMousePos.X, curMousePos.Y); // use a pen for lines rather than a brush (between 2 points)
        g.Dispose(); // mark the graphics object for collection
        oldMousePos = curMousePos; // set old to be this (so you get a continuous line)
}
```

You might consider an alternative way of doing the rendering - creating a Graphics object inside the mouse event is a bit dodgy.